# Remove rows by group if a condition meets in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like **df**:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c("2000", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2002", "2002", "2003", "2007", "2008"), 
                 id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
                 product = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), 
                 market = c("CHN", "USA", "CHN", "CAN", "CHN", "ECU", "CHN", "ESP", "IRL"), 
                 FP = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 FM = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1),
                 first_success = c(0,0,0,0,2002,2002,2002,0, 0)
                 )
```

and I want to remove (by id) the observations coming after the first_success year (defined in the variable **first_success** and taking the value of the year experiencing a success). If a given id (e.g. B) has not experienced success, then I want to keep these zeros. Therefore, in this case, I will only remove the 7th row:

```
df_new <- data.frame(year = c("2000", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2002", "2002", "2007", "2008"), 
                 id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
                 product = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "9"), 
                 market = c("CHN", "USA", "CHN", "CAN", "CHN", "ECU", "ESP", "IRL"), 
                 FP = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 FM = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                 first_success = c(0,0,0,0,2002,2002,0,0)
                 )
```

I have tried the following:

```
df %>% 
 group_by(id) %>%
 subset(., first_succes!=0 & first_success<year)
 filter(if(any(first_success)!=0) year<=first_success else TRUE)
```

But filter keeps the expression, instead of removing it (same for subset()).

Any idea?

---

### **EDIT**

The data also has some features like first_success taking value 0 after some already seen success (or even taking different values of first_success). Therefore, a more representative way of the case is **df**:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c("2000", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2002", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2007", "2008"), 
                 id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
                 product = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), 
                 market = c("CHN", "USA", "CHN", "CAN", "CHN", "ECU", "CHN", "NZL", "ESP", "IRL", "POR"), 
                 FP = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 FM = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 first_success = c(0,0,0,0,2002,2002,2002,0, 2005, 0, 0)
)
```

and I want to remove (by id) the observations coming after the first_success year (defined in the variable **first_success** and taking the value of the year experiencing a success). If a given id (e.g. B) has not experienced success, then I want to keep these zeros. Therefore, in this case, I will only remove the 7th , 8th, and the 9th row:

```
df_new <- data.frame(year = c("2000", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2002", "2002", "2007", "2008"), 
                 id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), 
                 product = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "10", "11"), 
                 market = c("CHN", "USA", "CHN", "CAN", "CHN", "ECU", "IRL", "POR"), 
                 FP = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 FM = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                 first_success = c(0,0,0,0,2002,2002, 0, 0)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0
df %>% 
  filter(first_success == 0 | year <= first_success, .by = id)

  year id product market FP FM first_success
1 2000  A       1    CHN  1  1             0
2 2000  A       2    USA  1  1             0
3 2001  A       3    CHN  1  0             0
4 2001  A       4    CAN  1  1             0
5 2002  A       5    CHN  1  0          2002
6 2002  A       6    ECU  1  1          2002
7 2007  B       8    ESP  1  1             0
8 2008  B       9    IRL  1  1             0
```

Before `dplyr 1.1.0`:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(first_success == 0 | year <= first_success) %>%
  ungroup()
```

---

Edit:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(cumsum(first_success) == 0 | year == first_success[first_success != 0][1]) %>%
  ungroup()

  year  id    product market    FP    FM first_success
1 2000  A     1       CHN        1     1             0
2 2000  A     2       USA        1     1             0
3 2001  A     3       CHN        1     0             0
4 2001  A     4       CAN        1     1             0
5 2002  A     5       CHN        1     0          2002
6 2002  A     6       ECU        1     1          2002
7 2007  B     10      IRL        1     1             0
8 2008  B     11      POR        1     1             0
```

Comment: It is not working in my machine ```Error in `filter()`:
! We detected a named input.
ℹ This usually means that you've used `=` instead of `==`.
ℹ Did you mean `.by == id`?```even when adopting .by=id

Comment: Check edit, this is because you have dplyr before 1.1.0

Comment: Thanks, it works but not for my specific data, that now it is better represented in my EDIT. Do you have an idea to overcome these cases?

Comment: yes see new edit

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes the trick! Could you add some lines to explain the logic behind?

Comment: I'd addvise to look at those conditions separately in a mutate call to understand what then mean